# Characteristic value of a Bluetooth Low Energy module gargled up in Android when processed

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

so to keep this short and sweet, everything works fine, from connecting to reading. But when I read the value of my characteristic, it's prefaced with random characters just like this:

"received:" "��2 ��1@ @ ��00 02 01 32 02 20 03 00 04 31 05 40 06 02 07 20 08 40 09 00"

The gibberish here being ofcourse "��2 ��1@ @   ��". It's always variable, and the longer the value of my characteristic, the more gibberish is produced. There are no spaces when I write my value, but that's not really a problem.

Does anybody know what could be causing this, and more importantly, how I can fix this?

Comment: The printing code whatever it looks like is having trouble.  Debug that first.  Assuming you are using some code to try and print the raw bytes here...

Comment: its not gibberish, you are not able to print it correctly. Why dont you show some code. Also add expected value of characteristic.